# Can we declare a property inside a method in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

We can declare a local variable inside a method. But why can't we declare a property or field in side a method?

In the below example I can able to declare a local variable inside a method but can't able to declare a property.

I am new to c#. So please correct me if I am wrong.

```
class Program
    {
        Public void Learn()
        {
           int f = 5;
          // int a { get; set;};
        }
    }
```

Comment: Because the compiler doesn't allow it.

Comment: Why would you want a property inside a method? Regardless of `static` or not. Also, that's not a *field*, it's a *variable*.

Comment: I am new to c#. So I am learning why can't we able to declare a property inside a method?

Comment: Downvotes nonwithstanding, this is not really a bad question! - It really depends on what kind of answer you want. One type is _because it makes no sense_; another is : _because that's how the laguage is defined._ For the former: What is gained by accessing it via `ClassName.MethodName.property` over `ClassName.property`?? For the latter: [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-properties) : _Properties are declared in the class block_

Comment: It should help to understand what [properties actually are](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) to understand why you cannot declare them inside methods. Properties are commonly used to represent public state at the class level, and fields to represent private state at the class level. Variables are declared at the method level since they do not represent the state of the object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can able to declare a field inside a static method

What you have declared is not a field, but a *local variable*. Fields don't exist in methods.

The reason for this is because fields and properties represent the state of an object. A `MusicPlayer` object may have things like `IsPlaying`, `Volume` as its properties. Those are the object's "state". The states belong to the object, not one particular method of that object, like `StartPlaying()`.

Local variables' purpose is to temporarily store some value to help the method do its job. They are kind of like pieces of scrap paper. You might have a method called `SolveQuadratic(double a, double b, double c)` and you might have a local variable called `discriminent` that stores `b * b - 4 * a * c`, so that you don't have to rewrite the expression `b * b - 4 * a * c` every time.

This is why you can't have properties inside methods, static or otherwise. They don't belong there.

Comment: Thanks @Sweeper for answering this. Could you please tell me what is the difference between a variable and field? I think both are same as a beginner.

Comment: @Gobind For beginners, a field is declared at the class level while a variable is declared in a method.

Comment: Thanks @Sweeper understood this.